# test whether a date list is now less than the date

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Here I have a list of dates that I formatted and I want as and as the day goes on my list so I reduced currentNow creates a variable for current date.

So I want to display the dates that are below the date.

So I did that but it does not work and I wonder if there is not a method to test whether the dates are inferior to the current date

```
    //format date now
    NSDateFormatter *currentNow = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [currentNow setDateFormat:@"d/MM/yyyy"];
    NSString *stringCurrentNow = [currentNow stringFromDate:now];
```

date test

```
// date test
    NSDateFormatter *dateTest = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateTest setDateFormat:@"d/MM/yyyy"];
    NSString *stringdateTest = [dateTest stringFromDate:date];
```

my test

```
if(stringdateTest > stringCurrentNow ){
        NSLog(@"not pass =>%@",stringCurrentNow);
}else{
        NSLog(@"the date has already passed => %@",stringdateTest);
}
```

but it does not work, he told me that the dates are already happen and when I look at the Result date is in two weeks, so my test not work or when I am not using the right method.

thank you in advance

Comment: Have you by any remote chance consulted the documentation for NSDate?

Comment: And did it occur to you that even if you could validly compare string pointers using `>` (which you can't), a date in d/MM/yyyy order will collate incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

1. You cannot compare objects using `>`, `<`, `==`, etc.  You'd end up comparing pointer addresses and an object's address has nothing to do with its value or sort order.
2. Where it's meaningful, subclasses of NSObject support the `compare:` method that compares two objects of similar class in a meaningful way for relative order.  All NSObject subclasses support `isEqual:`.
3. The [documentation for NSDate describes `compare:` is even more detail](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/compare%3a).
4. If you want to compare string dates instead of NSDates you need to get the date in a meaningful order, with the most-significant digits (the year) first.  Eg, yyyyMMdd.  And note that you should use fixed-width fields (hence "dd" not "d") or you will get some very peculiar sort orders.  And of course you need to use NSString's version of `compare:` when comparing the strings.

Comment: *"All subclasses of NSObject support the compare: method"* - are you sure about that?

Comment: @MartinR - Yeah, I guess all objects support `isEqual:`, but not necessarily `compare:`.